# exc bad instruction code exc i386 invop swift With NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tableview

I faced "exc bad instruction code exc i386 invop" issue. I struggling to solve this issue. If any one know this ping me...

**Issue**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("didselect")

    if(tableView == self.tabledata){
        print("Entered into tableview of listing")
        let savearr : NSArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedarray") as! NSArray

        let addarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"country") as! NSArray
        let sumarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"description") as! NSArray
        let titarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"title") as! NSArray
```

**Then I Tried This code:**

```
    if let savearr : NSArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedarray") as? NSArray
        {
        let addarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"country") as! NSArray
        let sumarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"description") as! NSArray
        let titarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"title") as! NSArray    
    let MenuViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "five") as! FiveStepsViewController

    MenuViewController.writeTitleString = String(describing: titarr[indexPath.row])

    MenuViewController.writeSummaryString = String(describing: sumarr[indexPath.row])

    MenuViewController.writeAddressString = String(describing: addarr[indexPath.row])

    //MenuViewController.writePriceString = String(describing: self.appDelegate.fivepricearray[indexPath.row])



        self.present(MenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("Error Occured while listing")
        }
```

Its always goes to else part..

Comment: Sure, I'm new to IOS and also stack overflow. I will change this post style from next post. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my post. :)

Comment: I'm still searching answer for this issue

Comment: Here i got a solution finally https://stackoverflow.com/q/45050957/7776881 refer this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/45050957/7776881) I found my Solution

**code:**

```
if ( titarr.count > 0 ) {
       // rest of your code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of issues arises generally when we try to forcefully unwrap the nil data. Recheck your keys. And try to follow as shown in below code snippet.

```
guard let savearr = UserDefaults.standard.object(forked: "savedArray") as? NSArray,
  let addarr = savearr.value(forKeyPath: "country") as? NSArray,
  let summer = savearr.value(forKeyPath: "description") as? NSArray,
  let titter = savearr.value(forKeyPath: "title") as? NSArray

  else { return nil }
```

Comment: yeah sure..where do u exactly facing problem

Answer (score 1):

```
 let MenuViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "five") as! FiveStepsViewController   

  if let savearr : NSArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedarray") as? NSArray
    {
    let addarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"country") as? NSArray
    let sumarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"description") as? NSArray
    let titarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"title") as? NSArray    


   MenuViewController.writeTitleString = String(describing: titarr[indexPath.row])

   MenuViewController.writeSummaryString = String(describing: sumarr[indexPath.row])

   MenuViewController.writeAddressString = String(describing: addarr[indexPath.row])

    }
    else {
        print("Error Occured while listing")
    }

 self.present(MenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Its always goes to else part!!

Comment: Can you please upload your code to save your arrays in userDefaults.