# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsrangeexception

**Error in log:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[**NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fdd8b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001143a6141 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fdf027d -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:] + 93
>       3   DropInn                             0x000000010d598fc4 _TFC7DropInn21ListingViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView14didSelectRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_T_ + 5972
>       4   DropInn                             0x000000010d599837 _TToFC7DropInn21ListingViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView14didSelectRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_T_ + 87
>       5   UIKit                               0x00000001122b3dcd -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1763
>       6   UIKit                               0x00000001122b3fe3 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 344
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001121697f3 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318
>       8   UIKit                               0x00000001121567bc _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 532
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000011218828c _afterCACommitHandler + 137
>       10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd7e717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23
>       11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd7e687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
>       12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd63720 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
>       13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd63016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
>       14  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000118249a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000011215d0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       16  DropInn                             0x000000010d240f47 main + 55
>       17  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000115fba65d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**Error screenshot:**

[image]

**Source code:**

```
let savearr : NSArray = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedarray") as! NSArray)

print("Savearr data ->", savearr)

let addarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"country") as! NSArray
let sumarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"description") as! NSArray
let titarr: NSArray = savearr.value(forKeyPath:"title") as! NSArray

appDelegate.indexrow = indexPath.row

print("addarr\(addarr)")
print("sumarr\(sumarr)")
print("titarr\(titarr)")

let MenuViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "five") as! FiveStepsViewController

MenuViewController.writeTitleString = String(describing: titarr[indexPath.row])

MenuViewController.writeSummaryString = String(describing: sumarr[indexPath.row])

MenuViewController.writeAddressString = String(describing: addarr[indexPath.row])

//MenuViewController.writePriceString = String(describing: self.appDelegate.fivepricearray[indexPath.row])

self.present(MenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Error shows in:**

```
MenuViewController.writeTitleString = String(describing: titarr[indexPath.row])

MenuViewController.writeSummaryString = String(describing: sumarr[indexPath.row])

MenuViewController.writeAddressString = String(describing: addarr[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: your array does not have element at index of indexpath.row check it before fetch `addarr[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Wait, I will check this line and i will back to here.

Comment: `if !(titarr[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).isEmpty{
                MenuViewController.writeTitleString = String(describing: titarr[indexPath.row])
            }else{
                print("titarr is empty")
            }`

Comment: I used this lines of code, but still its shows error

Comment: You're still trying to access out-of-bounds element, try `if titarr.count > indexPath.row { // do your stuff }`

Comment: Check if `titarr` `sumarr`  and `addarr` is having values

Comment: put all this code inside a check to see titarr count. You are still attempting to access an element out of bound in that if check.

Comment: Can you post your arrays which are printed in your console.

Comment: Sure wait @KrishnarjunBanoth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( titarr.count > 0 ) {
   // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @adam

Comment: Yes!,Finally I got result

Answer (score 5):

The [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrangeexception) has said that:

> **NSRangeException**
>
> Name of an exception that occurs when attempting to access outside the
>   bounds of some data, such as beyond the end of a string.

Specific in your case, one of the three array (or possibly all of them) `titarr`, `sumarr`, `addarr` is empty array and you're trying to access at index of an empty array => **NSRangeException**

To solve this problem, you can:

**Check if the array is non-empty:**

```
if !titarr.isEmpty {
    // titarr is non-empty
}
```

**Or, for more safely, check if the index you want to access does not exceed the data limit of the array:**

```
if titarr.count > yourIndex {
    // index is valid
}
```

**However, I prefer direct access to the index and if it is beyond bounds, it will return `nil`. To do this, refer to the [@kkuushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607485/nkukushkin)'s answer in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings?answertab=votes#tab-top).**

For example, something like this:

```
let titarr = [1, 2, 3]

// Access the index beyond bounds, value is nil, no NSRangeException
titarr[safe: 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!. I try this method and I will came back.